# "Insufficient Permission" when trying to authenticate to cloud-storage via apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts

I am about to give up on this as I can't find out what I am doing wrong.

I have a cloud-storage bucket with our companies billing data (json file objects written by google) that I am supposed to process into spreadsheets.

As there is no apps script API for oauth2, I am using the custom OAuth2 library provided by google with the key "1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF", and have setup the auth request as shown in this example for service accounts:https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs

The token is being created and put into the scripts property store, where I can view it. So far so good.

I have this code for requesting the token and then I am trying to list the contents of the bucket in the function "getFilesList()":

```
function getService() {
return OAuth2.createService('CloudStoreGrab-Service')
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

  .setPrivateKey(creds_private_key)
  .setIssuer(creds_client_email)
  .setSubject(creds_user_email)
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
  .setScope(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']);
}

function getFilesList() {
var service = getService();
service.reset();
if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/'+bucket+'/o'; 
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        muteHttpExceptions: true,        
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()               
        }
    });
}
Logger.log("Response:", response.getContentText())
}
```

No matter what I seem to try, the request always returns "403 Insufficient Permission". The service account has all necessary roles and permissions activated though (DwD, Storage-Administrator, Project-Owner). When I authenticate with the same credentials from gcloud and then browse the bucket with gsutils I can see the listing. This leads me to believe, that I am still requesting the auth token incorrectly. I tried using the generated token with curl and am getting the same Insufficient Permission response.

What am I doing wrong, while requesting the token?
Are the requested scopes too narrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Are the requested scopes too narrow?***

That they are. You can find the [OAuth scopes for Google's Cloud Storage API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#storagev1) listed below (you won't need to use all of them, pick the ones best suited to your use-case, the 1st and 5th scopes in the list should be sufficient):

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write

In future, you can find the required OAuth scopes for any Google API you need at the following link:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to add the cloud-platform.read-only scope and now everything works fine. We did have this scope set in the beginning but were obviously missing something else and thus took that scope out.